# Count top 10 user who started threads from a CSV file

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey I have this data in csv format with these headers

```
url,title,last_poster,total_posts,last_post_time,thread_starter
```

I am using SQL to query CSV files(http://harelba.github.io/q/)

I want to list top 10 thread_starters, what would the query look like?

Here is the data [CSV File](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/BiggBossCCDB/10c3f795f65b8903b9c058f9e83c00c5/raw/5404653f6f2b1f3c2bce28c6caff8d08d9b7ec3e/gistfile1.txt)

Comment: what is `top 10` for you in this case?

Comment: Top 10 users who created most number of threads (thread_starter column will tell you the user who started the thread)

Comment: Check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a query like this:

```
select thread_starter, count(*)
from ./file.csv
group by thread_starter
order by 2 desc;
```